# Updating Record using Lightning Connect

Tags: lightning-connect

I have configured an External Object using an Odata endpoint. However, it is a read-only object. Is there a way I can update the record in External Object- either via configuration or via. some Apex connector? If I write a custom Apex connector, will it be a good design to proceed with?

Comment: Just to add, I am using http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService Odata 4.0 endpoint

Comment: As far as I see there will be need for apex dev to maintain code .Its strange that odata 4.0 is not supported for write capabilities .Can you raise an Idea in the forums .

Comment: My Apologies, I found an option to enable a CRUD option on DSN. The functionality is active now. Thanks for help.